# How select item from listbox and insert it into sqllite3 database

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter, listboxitem

I want to select item from listbox and insert it into the sqllite3 database, the problem that `curselection()` value is a tuple, and I got this error:

```
self.cursorObj.execute("""INSERT INTO cars_selling_cashonly(cartype, buyername, paymentmethod, sellingdate, cashprice)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""",sellingcarinfos)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

I tried to use `list.get()` but it gives me the whole `Listbox` items,

my code:

```py
  def cashonlydb(self):
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
        self.cursorObj = self.conn.cursor()

        for cars in self.carlist.curselection():
            self.sell_choosedcard = self.carlist.get(cars)
            self.carlist.curselection()

        sellingcarinfos=(self.carlist.curselection(),self.buyernamevar.get(),self.sellingdatevar.get(),self.sellingpaymentmethodvar.get(),self.cash_value_var.get())
        self.cursorObj.execute("""INSERT INTO cars_selling_cashonly(cartype, buyername, paymentmethod, sellingdate, cashprice)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)""",sellingcarinfos)
        self.conn.commit()
```

I hope that I will get an useful answer this time, not as usual:)

Comment: What have you done to debug this? have you verified that `sellingcarsinfos` contains the data you expect it to contain?

Comment: @BryanOakley, to be honest, I am new to programming and I am trying to insert an item from Listbox(self. Carlist)

Comment: The first step in debugging is to validate your assumptions. For example, immediately before the `execute` command, add `print(sellingcarinfos)` to see what the value is before passing it to the function.

Comment: @BryanOakley I appreciate your response, I have printed(sellingcarinfos), and I got this:((), 'brock', '12/8/21'', '213', 'cash only) the first value is an empty tuple, and that's is the selected item from the Listbox, what I can do to convert it to string so I can add it to the sqllite3 database, thanks in advance.

Comment: Empty tuple means nothing is selected.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for your response, so what is the solution, I need to select an item from self.carlist

Comment: Selecting an item in a listbox is an user action.  So make sure that you have selected something in the listbox before calling this function.

Comment: @awc1668 100%, thanks, i will make a button so user can select the item them add it into sqllite3

Comment: @acw1668 I looked it up and found that the reason for that is: because the selected element from Listbox is an array, is there any way to convert it to a string so that I can include it in sqlite3????????

Comment: anybody help me I am stuck at.......

Comment: If there is only one item in the tuple, then use `curselection()[0]` to get the item.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks man appreciated your help, I solve it by converting tuple into a string using the join method.